# SQL Order By Within A Count(Distinct)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-order-by, distinct

I have the following tables:

```
filetype1
F1_ID | F1_ORDR | FILENAME
1     | 1        | file1.txt
2     | 2        | file2.txt
3     | 3        | file3.txt
4     | 2        | file4.txt
5     | 4        | file5.txt

filetype2
F2_ID | F2_ORDR | FILENAME
1     | 1        | file6.txt
2     | 2        | file7.txt
3     | 4        | file8.txt

ordr
OR_ID | OR_VENDOR
1     | 1
2     | 1
3     | 1
4     | 1

vendor
VE_ID | VE_NAME
1     | Company1
```

My goal is to have a list of vendors and a count of the number of orders where a file is connected for each type. For example, the end result of this data should be:

```
VENDOR   | OR_CT | F1_CT | F2_CT
Company1 | 4        | 4        | 3
```

Because at least 1 type1 file was attached to 4 distinct orders and at least 1 type2 file was attached to 3 distinct orders. Currently my SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT vendor.ve_id, vendor.ve_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(or_id)
        FROM ordr
        WHERE ordr.or_vendor = vendor.ve_id) as OR_COUNT, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f1_order)
        FROM filetype1 INNER JOIN ordr ON filetype1.f1_ordr = ordr.or_id
        WHERE ordr.or_vendor = vendor.ve_id) as F1_CT,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f2_ordr)
        FROM filetype2 INNER JOIN ordr ON filetype2.f2_ordr = ordr.or_id
        WHERE ordr.or_vendor = vendor.ve_id) as F2_CT
FROM vendor
ORDER BY vendor.ve_name
```

Unfortunately this yields the following results:

```
VENDOR   | OR_COUNT | F1_COUNT | F2_COUNT
Company1 | 4        | 5        | 3
```

My only guess is that because I'm using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` the `COUNT` is automatically assuming the `DISTINCT` is ordering by `F1_ID` instead of by `F1_ORDR`

If anyone can assist me on how to tell the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` to order by `F1_ORDR` that would be most helpful. I have searched the vast internet for a solution but its hard to explain what I want to a search engine, forums, etc. My database uses Microsoft SQL Server. My knowledge of database management is almost completely self taught, so I'm just glad I made it this far on my own. My expertise is in web design. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL yields the result you want for me.

Two pieces of advice

1. Order is a bad name for a table - it conflicts with a reserved word, and will cause you no end of hassle
2. You should join your tables like so

   `FROM filetype1 
       inner join [order]
           on filetype1.f1_order = or_id`

rather than using a where clause

Perhaps try this instead

```
select 
    vendor.VE_ID, vendor.VE_NAME,   
    count(distinct or_id),
    count(distinct f1_order),
    count(distinct f2_order)

from 
    vendor
        left join [order]
            on vendor.VE_ID = [order].OR_VENDOR
        inner join filetype1 
            on [order].OR_ID = filetype1.F1_ORDER
        left join filetype2
            on [order].OR_ID = filetype2.F2_ORDER
group by
    vendor.VE_ID, vendor.VE_NAME
```

Comment: If I wanted a count of the total files connected to an order, my SQL would work. Unfortunately, the count needs to be the number of orders that have any amount of the file type attached. So I would want it to yield 4 as the result of f1_ct, not 5.

Comment: It does. Or at least, it does for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
vdr.VE_NAME   
,COUNT(DISTINCT OR_ID) AS OR_ID 
,COUNT(DISTINCT ft1.F1_ORDER) AS FT1_COUNT
,COUNT(DISTINCT ft2.F2_ORDER) AS FT2_COUNT
FROM
    vendor vdr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [order] odr
        ON vdr.VE_ID = odr.OR_VENDOR
    INNER JOIN filetype1 ft1
        ON  odr.OR_ID = ft1.F1_ORDER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN filetype2 ft2
        ON odr.OR_ID = ft2.F2_ORDER
GROUP BY
    vdr.VE_ID
    ,vdr.VE_NAME
```

Comment: Aww, looks like podiluska beat me to it. Anyhow, your original code also yields the proper results for me as well so I'm not sure what the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you this:

Merge filetype1 and filetype2 tables in one table(filetype) and add another field named - f_type(for instance) of type INT or TINTYINT to store the filetype (1 or 2). This has the benefits of painlessly adding another filetype later
Now the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
vendor.ve_name,
count(DISTINCT filetype.f_order),
filetype.f_type
FROM 
   filetype
       INNER JOIN `order`
           ON filetype.f_order = `order`.or_id
       INNER JOIN vendor
           ON `order`.or_vendor = vendor.ve_id
   GROUP BY vendor.ve_id,filetype.f_type
```

This will give the count of orders for filetype.

For the total orders just add another query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `order`
```